# Add trial experience to wp8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8, trial

I have some issue here with a guide from geekchamp how to implement trial mode to my app. Now my app is for windows phone 8 and the guide for the implementation is for wp7 but it should not be any problem.

I have followed every step but nothing is happening when I laucnh the app from that I have laucned it tombestoneing it and then jump back in to it.

The popup does not appear.

Link to guide:
[geekchamp](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-windows-phone-7-trial-application-advanced-buy-now-implementation)

Comment: Can you please post your code so that we can take a look at it? Did you tried debugging the code and see if you get any exceptions?

Comment: Also, here is a nice sample to implement trail experience in windows phone 8: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Trial-Experience-Sample-c58f21af

Comment: I did solve it. Hade missed some settings for the debugger. Really sorry to post this question when the answer was so simple

Comment: Good to know that you fixed the issue. Can you please post your findings and settings as an answers so that it help others facing the same situation?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question with help from an article from geekchamp. Its for Windows Phone 7 but its also works for Windows Phone 8.

The steps where in 3 articles that i have listed below:

[Implementation and Best Practices](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-windows-phone-7-trial-application-implementation-and-best-practices)

[Adding buy-now functionality](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-windows-phone-7-trial-application-adding-buy-now-functionality)

[Advanced Buy Now Implementation](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/creating-a-windows-phone-7-trial-application-advanced-buy-now-implementation)

I did follow all these three to get the result I wanted.